# (Async & await) vs (without Async & await) in Web API

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am new with Async and await using C# Programming. In WebAPI, we have created two API Controllers one with Async and await Programming and other is without that. We have done load testing using JMeter and we have got following results.

```
Users          Sync                                         Async
```

---

```
100           No Errors                                    No Errors                             
500           No Errors                                    No Errors                             
750           No Errors                                    Errors - (59.0 %) - 502 Bad Gateway   
763           No Errors                                    Errors                                
764           No Errors                                    Errors                                
765           Errors - (0.13 %) - 502 Bad Gateway          Errors
1000          Errors                                      Errors
```

Can you any please explain/suggest which approach is best or how can we proceed ?

## API Code :

## GetPersonalDetailsController - Async and await Used

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GET([FromUri] RequestQueryListDTO objAPIRequest)
{
    DateTime startResponseTime = DateTime.Now;
    Response objResponse = null;
    string strResponse = string.Empty;
    var HeaderType = Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
    ProductBAL objProductBAL = null;
    try
    {
        if (objAPIRequest != null)
        {
            Task<Response> tskGetProductDetails = Task<Response>.Run(() =>
            {
                objProductBAL = new ProductBAL();
                return objProductBAL.GetProductDetails(objAPIRequest);

                //Business Access Layer Logic calling
            });
            objResponse = await tskGetProductDetails;
        }
        else
        {
            objResponse = new Response();
            objResponse.ReturnCode = -1;
            objResponse.ReturnMessage = "Missing Parameters.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        \\ Exception Logging
    }
    finally
    {
        objProductBAL = null;
    }
    objResponse.ResponseTime = Math.Round((DateTime.Now - startResponseTime).TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
    if (objResponse.ReturnCode == Convert.ToInt32(General.ReturnCode))
    {
        return Content<Response>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, objResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(objResponse);
    }
}
```

========================================================================

## GetPDPController  - Without using Async and await

```
public IHttpActionResult GET([FromUri] RequestQueryListDTO objAPIRequest)
{
    DateTime startResponseTime = DateTime.Now;
    Response objResponse = null;
    string strResponse = string.Empty;
    var HeaderType = Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;

    try
    {
        if (objAPIRequest != null)
        {
            //Business Access Layer Logic calling
        }
        else
        {
            objResponse = new Response();
            objResponse.ReturnCode = -1;
            objResponse.ReturnMessage = "Missing Parameters.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception Logging Code
    }
    finally
    {
        objProductBAL = null;
    }
    objResponse.ResponseTime = Math.Round((DateTime.Now - startResponseTime).TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
    if (objResponse.ReturnCode == Convert.ToInt32(General.ReturnCode))
    {
        return Content<Response>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, objResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(objResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your Async version is wrong for starters.  You are spinning up tasks to call a non Async method which is just going to block on I/O

Comment: What occurs here is a deadlock. Possibly you can use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` as a hack to avoid the deadlock. My suggestion https://pastebin.com/3GkzmMwh

Comment: you need a async await version of `objProductBAL.GetProductDetails(objAPIRequest);`

Comment: also `if (objAPIRequest != null)    {` logic is flawed i think... the request itself would fail if it was null, hense you would never reach that code, you should be checking the properties

Comment: Using `await Task.Run` in a controller makes no sense. You must only await non-cpu-bound tasks such as a DB call (e.g. `await query.ToListAsnc()`) or a call to another web service (e.g. `await request.SendAsync()`). Assuming `GetProductDetails` eventually does some database operation, you must rewrite that method so that it is async (and returns a `Task<Result>`) and so that it uses `await` to do a the DB call.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is have two methods, one Async and one not. That way you can test more.

- GetProductDetails
- GetProductDetailsAsync

you would then need to change the signature of the calling method aka GET

```
public IHttpActionResult GET([FromUri] RequestQueryListDTO objAPIRequest)
{
    var objResponse = new Response();

    //check the properties of objAPIRequest
    if(bad)
    {
        //add stuff if you want
        return Content<Response>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, objResponse);
    }

    //Business Access Layer Logic calling
    //-----------------------
    ProductBAL objProductBAL = new ProductBAL();

    //you need to change this to async
    var productDetails = objProductBAL.GetProductDetails(objAPIRequest);
    //-----------------------

    return Ok(objResponse);
}
```